# Crashplan won't install properly

Tags: bash, 13.10, crashplan

I have downloaded an application called CrashPlan for backups. It comes with the install.sh script below. I ran it but received the following errors. How do i fix this?

```
install.sh: 31: [: x: unexpected operator
install.sh: 100: [: xy: unexpected operator
install.sh: 104: [: y: unexpected operator
  installing as current user
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 127: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 138: install.sh: [[: not found
install.sh: 177: install.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Install.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

#############################################################
# Linux Client Installer Script
#############################################################

# variables defined in install.defaults
# APP_BASENAME = human-readable application name
# DIR_BASENAME = dir name
# DOWNLOAD_HOST = where to get the jre

SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname ${0}`
if [ ! -f "${SCRIPT_DIR}/install.defaults" ] ; then
    echo "${SCRIPT_DIR}/install.defaults MISSING!"
    exit 1
fi

. ${SCRIPT_DIR}/install.defaults

REQDBINS="grep sed cpio gzip cut head tail who"
OKJAVA="1.5 1.6 1.7"

TARGETDIR=/usr/local/${DIR_BASENAME}
BINSDIR=/usr/local/bin
MANIFESTDIR=/usr/local/var/${DIR_BASENAME}
INITDIR=/etc/init.d
RUNLEVEL=`who -r | sed -e 's/^.*\(run-level [0-9]\).*$/\1/' | cut -d \  -f 2`
RUNLVLDIR=/etc/rc${RUNLEVEL}.d

SRC_USER=${SUDO_USER}
if [ "x${SRC_USER}" == "x" ] ; then
    SRC_USER=${USER}
fi

USERNAME="`id -un`"

prepdir() {
    if [ ! -d "${1}" ] ; then
        echo -n "${1} does not exist.  Create $1? (y/n) [y] "
        read YN_PD
        if [ "x${YN_PD}" == "x" ] ; then
            YN_PD=y
        fi
        if [ "${YN_PD}" == "y" ] ; then
            mkdir -p "${1}"
            if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo "Failed to create ${1}.  Please check your configuration."
                return 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Please check your configuration."
            return 1
        fi
    fi
    return 0
}

promptForJVMDownload() {

    echo -n "Would you like to download the JRE and dedicate it to ${APP_BASENAME}? (y/n) [y] "
    read JAVADL
    if [ "x${JAVADL}" == "x" ] ; then
        JAVADL=y
    fi

    if [ "${JAVADL}" == "y" ] ; then
        JAVACOMMON="DOWNLOAD"
        echo "  jre will be downloaded"
    else
        echo ""
        echo "We're sorry, ${APP_BASENAME} requires a valid Sun JRE or OpenJDK. Please install one and then"
        echo "rerun this installer. Exiting."
        exit 1
    fi
    return 0
}

# welcome- avoid printing duplicate messages if we're recalling ourself
if [ "${1}" != "recall" ] ; then
    echo ""
    echo "Welcome to the ${APP_BASENAME} Installer."
    echo ""
    echo -n "Press enter to continue with installation. "
    read ENTER

    # Basic requirements - 
    echo ""
    echo "Validating environment..."
fi

# Basic requirements
if [ "${USERNAME}" != "root" ] ; then
    echo ""
    echo "NOTE: You are apparently not installing as root. While it is recommended to"
    echo "install as root it is not required. If you continue to install as ${USERNAME}"
    echo "then ${APP_BASENAME} will only be able to back up files readable by ${USERNAME}."
    echo ""
    echo -n "Would you like to switch users and install as root? (y/n) [y] "
    read YN
    if [ "x${YN}" == "x" ] ; then
        YN=y
    fi

    if [ "${YN}" == "y" ] ; then
        echo "  switching to root"
        sudo ${0} recall
        exit 0
    else
        echo "  installing as current user"

        TARGETDIR=${HOME}/${DIR_BASENAME}
        BINSDIR=
        MANIFESTDIR=${TARGETDIR}/manifest
        INITDIR=
        RUNLVLDIR=
    fi
else
    echo "  detected root permissions"
fi

# ===============================================================================
# Validate the environment by verifying that all necessary binaries are present
# ===============================================================================
for BIN in $REQDBINS ; do

    BIN_PATH=`which $BIN 2> /dev/null`
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: $BIN not found and is required for install. Exiting"
        exit 1
    fi
done
#echo ""

# ===============================================================================
# Continue validation by verifying the existence of a supported Java VM
# ===============================================================================
JAVACOMMON=`which java`
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "No Java VM could be found in your path"
    promptForJVMDownload
fi


# Setup ARCHIVE var to point to the cpio archive.  This will be used here to extract what we need
# to execute the Java comparison below and will be used later by the script to 
# actually extract everything.
ARCHIVE=`ls ./*_*.cpi`

if [[ $JAVACOMMON != "DOWNLOAD" ]]; then

    # Evaluate the Java environment
    mkdir ./lib
    cat $ARCHIVE | gzip -dc - | cpio -i --no-preserve-owner ./lib/com.backup42.desktop.jar
    $JAVACOMMON -classpath ./lib/com.backup42.desktop.jar com.code42.utils.JavaEnvironment > /tmp/foo.sh
    source /tmp/foo.sh
    rm /tmp/foo.sh
    rm -rf ./lib

    # Check the Java version to make sure we have something workable
    JAVAVERCHECK=0
    for CANDIDATE in $OKJAVA; do
        if [[ $CANDIDATE == $JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION ]] ; then
            JAVAVERCHECK=1
        fi
    done
    if [[ $JAVAVERCHECK -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "The current version of Java ($JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION) is incompatible with $APP_BASENAME."
        echo "Please install one of the following version of the Sun JRE or OpenJDK: $OKJAVA"
        exit 1
    fi  

    # Make sure we've got either HotSpot or OpenJDK
    echo $JAVA_VM_NAME | grep OpenJDK > /dev/null 2>&1
    IS_OPENJDK=$?
    echo $JAVA_VM_NAME | grep HotSpot > /dev/null 2>&1
    IS_HOTSPOT=$?
    if [[ ! ($IS_OPENJDK || $IS_HOTSPOT) ]]; then
        echo ""
        echo "The current installed version of Java is not supported."
        echo "$APP_BASENAME requires the Sun JRE or OpenJDK."
        exit 1
    fi
fi


echo ""
echo "You must review and agree to the EULA before installation."
echo ""
echo -n "Press enter to read the EULA. "
read ENTER

# EULA Time
more ./EULA.txt

agreed=0
while [ "${agreed}" == "0" ] ; do
    echo ""
    echo -n "Do you accept and agree to be bound by the EULA? (yes/no) "
    read reply
    case ${reply} in
        [yY] | [yY][eE][sS])
            agreed=1
            ;;
        [nN] | [nN][oO])
            echo "If you do not agree to the license then ${APP_BASENAME} may not be installed. Exiting.";
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done


INTERVIEW=0
while [ ${INTERVIEW} == 0 ] ; do

    INTERVIEWSUB=0
    while [ ${INTERVIEWSUB} == 0 ] ; do
        echo ""
        echo -n "What directory do you wish to install ${APP_BASENAME} to? [${TARGETDIR}] "
        read TARGETDIR_X        
        if [ "x${TARGETDIR_X}" != "x" ] ; then
            TARGETDIR=${TARGETDIR_X}
            MANIFESTDIR=${TARGETDIR}/manifest
        fi

        prepdir "${TARGETDIR}"
        if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
            INTERVIEWSUB=1
        fi
    done


    if [ "${USERNAME}" == "root" ] ; then
        INTERVIEWSUB=0
        while [ ${INTERVIEWSUB} == 0 ] ; do
            echo ""
            echo -n "What directory do you wish to link the ${APP_BASENAME} executable to? [${BINSDIR}] "
            read BINSDIR_X
            if [ "x${BINSDIR_X}" != "x" ] ; then
                BINSDIR=${BINSDIR_X}
            fi
            prepdir ${BINSDIR}
            if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
                INTERVIEWSUB=1
            fi
        done
    fi

    INTERVIEWSUB=0
    while [ ${INTERVIEWSUB} == 0 ] ; do
        echo ""
        echo -n "What directory do you wish to store backups in? [${MANIFESTDIR}] "
        read MANIFESTDIR_X
        if [ "x${MANIFESTDIR_X}" != "x" ] ; then
            MANIFESTDIR=${MANIFESTDIR_X}
        fi
        prepdir ${MANIFESTDIR}
        if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
            INTERVIEWSUB=1
        fi
    done

    if [ "${USERNAME}" == "root" ] ; then
        INTERVIEWSUB=0
        while [ ${INTERVIEWSUB} == 0 ] ; do
            echo ""
            echo -n "What directory contains your SYSV init scripts? [${INITDIR}] "
            read INITDIR_X
            if [ "x${INITDIR_X}" != "x" ] ; then
                INITDIR=${INITDIR_X}
            fi
            prepdir ${INITDIR}
            if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
                INTERVIEWSUB=1
            fi
        done

        INTERVIEWSUB=0
        while [ ${INTERVIEWSUB} == 0 ] ; do
            echo ""
            echo -n "What directory contains your runlevel init links? [${RUNLVLDIR}] "
            read RUNLVLDIR_X
            if [ "x${RUNLVLDIR_X}" != "x" ] ; then
                RUNLVLDIR=${RUNLVLDIR_X}
            fi
            prepdir ${RUNLVLDIR}
            if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
                INTERVIEWSUB=1
            fi
        done
    fi
    echo ""
    echo "Your selections:"
    echo ${APP_BASENAME} will install to: ${TARGETDIR}
    if [ "${USERNAME}" == "root" ] ; then
        echo And put links to binaries in: ${BINSDIR}
    fi
    echo And store datas in: ${MANIFESTDIR}
    if [ "${USERNAME}" == "root" ] ; then
        echo Your init.d dir is: ${INITDIR}
        echo Your current runlevel directory is: ${RUNLVLDIR}
    fi
    echo ""
    echo -n "Is this correct? (y/n) [y] "
    read YN
    if [ "x${YN}" == "x" ] ; then
        YN=y
    fi

    if [ "${YN}" == "y" ] ; then
        INTERVIEW=1
    fi
done

# INSTALL TIME ===============================================
echo ""

# is crashplan already there?
if [ -f ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars ]; then
    echo "CrashPlan appears to already be installed in the specified location:"
    echo "  ${TARGETDIR}"
    echo "Please uninstall and then try this install again."
    exit 1
fi

# create a file that has our install vars so we can later uninstall
echo "" > ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
echo "TARGETDIR=${TARGETDIR}" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
echo "BINSDIR=${BINSDIR}" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
echo "MANIFESTDIR=${MANIFESTDIR}" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
echo "INITDIR=${INITDIR}" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
echo "RUNLVLDIR=${RUNLVLDIR}" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
NOW=`date +%Y%m%d`
echo "INSTALLDATE=$NOW" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
cat ${SCRIPT_DIR}/install.defaults >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars

# keep track of the processor architecture
PARCH=`uname -m`

#download java
if [[ $JAVACOMMON == "DOWNLOAD" ]]; then
    if [[ $PARCH == "x86_64" ]]; then
        JVMURL="http://${DOWNLOAD_HOST}/linuxjvm/jre1.6.0_25_x64.tgz"
    else
        JVMURL="http://${DOWNLOAD_HOST}/linuxjvm/jre1.6.0_25_i586.tgz"
    fi
    JVMFILE=`basename ${JVMURL}`
    if [[ -f ${JVMFILE} ]]; then
        echo ""
        echo "Download of the JVM found. We'll try to use it, but if it's only a partial"
        echo "copy of the file then this will fail. If that happens please remove the file"
        echo "and try again."
        echo "JRE Archive: ${JVMFILE}"
        echo ""
    else

        # Start by looking for wget
        WGET_PATH=`which wget 2> /dev/null`
        if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
            echo "    downloading the JRE using wget"
            $WGET_PATH $JVMURL
            if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
                echo "Unable to download JRE; please check network connection"
                exit 1
            fi
        else

            CURL_PATH=`which curl 2> /dev/null`
            if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
                echo "    downloading the JRE using curl"
                $CURL_PATH $JVMURL -o `basename $JVMURL`
                if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
                    echo "Unable to download JRE; please check network connection"
                    exit 1
                fi
            else
                echo "Could not find wget or curl.  You must install one of these utilities"
                echo "in order to download a JVM"
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    fi

    HERE=`pwd`
    cd ${TARGETDIR}
    # Extract into ./jre
    tar -xzf "${HERE}/${JVMFILE}"
    cd "${HERE}"
    echo "JAVACOMMON=${TARGETDIR}/jre/bin/java" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
    echo "Java Installed."
else
    echo "JAVACOMMON=${JAVACOMMON}" >> ${TARGETDIR}/install.vars
fi  

# Definition of ARCHIVE occurred above when we extracted the JAR we need to evaluate Java environment
echo Unpacking ${HERE}/${ARCHIVE} ... 
HERE=`pwd`
cd ${TARGETDIR}
cat "${HERE}/${ARCHIVE}" | gzip -d -c - | cpio -i --no-preserve-owner
cd "${HERE}"

# custom?
if [ -d .Custom ]; then
  echo Copying .Custom to ${TARGETDIR}
  cp -Rp .Custom "${TARGETDIR}"
fi
if [ -d custom ]; then
  echo Copying custom to ${TARGETDIR}
  cp -Rp custom "${TARGETDIR}"
fi
if [ -d Custom ]; then
  echo Copying custom to ${TARGETDIR}
  cp -Rp custom "${TARGETDIR}"
fi

#update the configs for file storage
if grep "<manifestPath>.*</manifestPath>" ${TARGETDIR}/conf/default.service.xml > /dev/null
    then
        sed -i "s|<manifestPath>.*</manifestPath>|<manifestPath>${MANIFESTDIR}</manifestPath>|g" ${TARGETDIR}/conf/default.service.xml
    else
        sed -i "s|<backupConfig>|<backupConfig>\n\t\t\t<manifestPath>${MANIFESTDIR}</manifestPath>|g" ${TARGETDIR}/conf/default.service.xml
fi

# the log dir
LOGDIR=${TARGETDIR}/log
chmod 777 $LOGDIR

# desktop init script
GUISCRIPT=${TARGETDIR}/bin/${APP_BASENAME}Desktop
cp scripts/${APP_BASENAME}Desktop ${GUISCRIPT}
chmod 755 ${GUISCRIPT}
#sed -imod "s|TARGETDIR=.*|TARGETDIR=${TARGETDIR}|" ${GUISCRIPT} && rm -rf ${GUISCRIPT}mod

# link to bin if appropriate
if [ "x${BINSDIR}" != "x" ] ; then
    ln -s ${GUISCRIPT} ${BINSDIR}/${APP_BASENAME}Desktop
fi


# Install the control script for the service
INITSCRIPT=${TARGETDIR}/bin/${APP_BASENAME}Engine
cp scripts/${APP_BASENAME}Engine ${INITSCRIPT}
cp scripts/run.conf ${TARGETDIR}/bin
chmod 755 ${INITSCRIPT}

# Install the init script and modify it by applying variables currently defined in this context
# If the user is not installing as root then we install into the bin directory only.
INIT_INSTALL_DIR=${TARGETDIR}/bin
if [ "x${INITDIR}" != "x" ] ; then
   INIT_INSTALL_DIR=${INITDIR}
fi

# Perform substitution on the init script; we need to make the value of INITSCRIPT available
# to what lives in /etc/init.d
SEDEXPRSUB=`echo $INITSCRIPT | sed 's/\//\\\\\//g'`
SEDEXPR="s/<INITSCRIPT>/$SEDEXPRSUB/g"
sed $SEDEXPR scripts/${DIR_BASENAME} > ${INIT_INSTALL_DIR}/${DIR_BASENAME}
chmod 755 ${INIT_INSTALL_DIR}/${DIR_BASENAME}

if [ "x${RUNLVLDIR}" != "x" ] ; then

   # Now that we should have a working init script let's link in the runlevel scripts   
   ln -s ${INIT_INSTALL_DIR}/${DIR_BASENAME} ${RUNLVLDIR}/S99${DIR_BASENAME}
fi


# copy the desktop launcher into place
if [ -d "/home/${SRC_USER}/Desktop" ] ; then
    DESKTOP_LAUNCHER="/home/${SRC_USER}/Desktop/${APP_BASENAME}.desktop"

    # which icon are we using? custom if it exists
    DESKTOP_ICON_PATH=${TARGETDIR}/skin/icon_app_128x128.png
    if [ -f ${TARGETDIR}/skin/custom/icon_app_64x64.png ] ; then
        DESKTOP_ICON_PATH=${TARGETDIR}/skin/custom/icon_app_64x64.png
    fi
    if [ -f ${TARGETDIR}/skin/custom/icon_app_128x128.png ] ; then
        DESKTOP_ICON_PATH=${TARGETDIR}/skin/custom/icon_app_128x128.png
    fi

    # use 'su' only if we're operating as root
    if [ "${USERNAME}" == "root" ] ; then
        su ${SRC_USER} -c "cp scripts/${APP_BASENAME}.desktop ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}"
        su ${SRC_USER} -c "chmod +x ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}"
        su ${SRC_USER} -c "sed -imod \"s|Exec=.*|Exec=${GUISCRIPT}|\" ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER} && rm -rf ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}mod"
        su ${SRC_USER} -c "sed -imod \"s|Icon=.*|Icon=${DESKTOP_ICON_PATH}|\" ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER} && rm -rf ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}mod"
    else
        cp scripts/${APP_BASENAME}.desktop ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}
        chmod +x ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}
        sed -imod "s|Exec=.*|Exec=${GUISCRIPT}|" ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER} && rm -rf ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}mod
        sed -imod "s|Icon=.*|Icon=${DESKTOP_ICON_PATH}|" ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER} && rm -rf ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}mod
    fi
fi

# Check for max_user_watches and suggest updating if necessary.  Many distros use 8192 by default
# so we use this value as a baseline.
INOTIFY_WATCHES=`cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
if [[ $INOTIFY_WATCHES -le 8192 ]]; then
  echo ""
  echo "Your Linux system is currently configured to watch $INOTIFY_WATCHES files in real time."
  echo "We recommend using a larger value; see the CrashPlan support site for details"
  echo ""
fi

# Start the servce
${INITSCRIPT} start

# call out the "service has been started" by creating a pause
echo ""
echo "${APP_BASENAME} has been installed and the Service has been started automatically."
echo ""
echo -n "Press Enter to complete installation. "
read ENTER

echo ""
echo "Important directories:"
echo "  Installation:"
echo "    ${TARGETDIR}"
echo "  Logs:"
echo "    ${TARGETDIR}/log"
echo "  Default archive location:"
echo "    ${MANIFESTDIR}"

# if we installed as root make sure they see 'sudo' in front of the Engine start
SUDO_PREFIX="sudo "
if [ "${USERNAME}" != "root" ] ; then
    SUDO_PREFIX=""
fi
echo ""
echo "Start Scripts:"
echo "  ${SUDO_PREFIX}${INITSCRIPT} start|stop"
echo "  ${GUISCRIPT}"

echo ""
echo "You can run the ${APP_BASENAME} Desktop UI locally as your own user or connect"
echo "a remote Desktop UI to this Service via port-forwarding and manage it"
echo "remotely. Instructions for remote management are in the readme files"
echo "placed in your installation directory:"
echo "  ${TARGETDIR}/doc"
echo ""
if [ "x${DISPLAY}" != "x" ] ; then
    echo -n "Would you like to start ${APP_BASENAME}Desktop? (y/n) [y] "
    read reply
    if [ "x${reply}" == "x" ] ; then
        reply=y
    fi
    case ${reply} in
        [yY] | [yY][eE][sS])
            # use 'su' only if we're operating as root
            if [ "${USERNAME}" == "root" ] ; then
                su ${SRC_USER} -c "${GUISCRIPT}"
            else
                ${GUISCRIPT}
            fi
            ;;
    esac
fi

echo ""
echo "To start the Desktop UI:"
if [ "x${BINSDIR}" != "x" ] ; then
    echo "  ${BINSDIR}/${APP_BASENAME}Desktop"
else
echo "  ${GUISCRIPT}"
fi

echo ""
echo "Installation is complete. Thank you for installing ${APP_BASENAME} for Linux."
echo ""
```

Answer (score 2):

I executed install.sh incorrected. I used the command `sh install.sh` when I should have executed it as `bash install.sh`.